# How to stop exchanges/queues from receiving messages temporarily?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

My deployment is like as shown below:

client -> relay server -> server

The relay server is a rabbitmq service which contains an exchange and many queues which are bound to this exchange. Any message pushed to this exchange with a mapping routing key will push the message to appropriate queue.

Now, my requirement is, when server is down I should avoid/block "relay server" from accepting any further messages.

Please help. Dead message queue didn't work.

Comment: I don't know anything about `rabbitmq`, but since nobody is responding in such a long while, I'll offer something that seems reasonable and doable regardless the technology: Have between the client and the relay server a redirecting server to pass on requests to the relay server if it's up (or if you tell it its up). The redirecting server should have 99.9% uptime, and all the updates and stuff can then be done on the relay server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer your question as i am working with RabbitMQ currently. As far i know there is no way blocking messages to be pushed to queue. You have to achieve this programatically.

Step 1: Poll server for its running status before you want to push message to queue.

Step 2: If server is running go ahead pushing message to queue if not you know what you want to do.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`server` can create queues with the `x-expires` set which means:

> How long a queue can be unused for before it is automatically deleted
>   (milliseconds).

Thus, if server is down, the associated queue will be deleted and no messages will be queued.

[See the documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl)